# Name of this enum-based design pattern to get the type

Tags: design-patterns, interfaces, enum, switch-statement

I have been using a pattern in a lot of places (mainly C#) that I would like to know the name of.

Here is an example of it in C#:

```csharp
public enum ThingType
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}

public interface IThing
{
    ThingType Type
    { get; }
}

public class ThingA : IThing
{
    public ThingType Type => ThingType.A;
}

public class ThingB : IThing
{
    public ThingType Type => ThingType.B;
}

public class ThingC : IThing
{
    public ThingType Type => ThingType.C;
}
```

As long as all implementations of `IThing` have a corresponding member in the enum, I can safely cast to the actual type of an `IThing` after checking the value of `IThing.Type`.

```csharp
public void HandleThing(IThing thing)
{
    switch(thing.Type)
    {
        case ThingType.A:
            ThingA a = (ThingA)thing;
            // Doing something with a...
            break;

        case ThingType.B:
            ThingB b = (ThingB)thing;
            // Doing something with b...
            break;

        case ThingType.C:
            ThingC c = (ThingC)thing;
            // Doing something with c...
            break;
    }
}
```

---

I apologize if this question is a duplicate, I went through a few pages of search results for multiple different search phrases and I couldn't find this question already.

Comment: You're basically doing the opposite of subtype polymorphism by exposing internal details. I am not sure whether this anti-pattern has a name.

Comment: This is how we used to do polymorphic object-based programming in C before OOP languages, tagged unions and switch statements.

Comment: @VincentSavard, Could you write an answer showing the pattern I am missing that is opposite to this anti-pattern?

Comment: Is the purpose of finding a name for whatever this is so that you can go Google it and read about it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Because it is a prevalent "pattern" throughout our code, I wanted to know if there was a well-established name for it. It has come up in discussion enough that having an off-hand name for it is necessary.

Comment: It doesn't have a name because it's not a pattern - it's an abuse of polymorphism. All of your `"Do something with x..."` should be encapsulated by `x` and should simply be invoked via `IThing.DoSomething`

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you need an enum for this.  Objects already know what type they are.  `switch(typeof(thing))` or `switch(thing.GetType())`

Comment: Anyways, I agree with @AntP  and Vincent on this.  It's essentially a re-invention of runtime polymorphism.

Comment: @AntP, I'm using the word "Pattern" in the broadest sense; It looks similar in multiple places. I realize that in the context of software engineering that things *are* or *are not* "Patterns" by another stricter definition.

Comment: @AntP, As for *why* I use this "pattern", the `do something with X` code is arguably not within the scope of X. For example, I have a GUI that needs to restructure itself based on the actual type of X and provide buttons that call functions that exist on only one subtype. Robert Harvey has a good point though, that `typeof(thing)` would work just as well. I find it slightly less readable to use that in branching statements though.

Comment: Overall, it looks vaguely like a [Factory Method](https://www.javatpoint.com/factory-method-design-pattern).

Comment: @Romen then you need an interface to pass to x that it can operate on as appropriate. Read up on polymorphism and tell don't ask, your "pattern" violates basic OOP concepts. If it is behaviour that varies per IThing then it is in the scope of IThing by definition. That's how OOP is designed to work.

Comment: @AntP, Deleted my previous comment after reading about "Tell-don't-ask". That principle isn't really relevant to what's going on in that switch statement. The class that contains the switch statement is a Windows Form that is modifying *itself* based on the type and state of a/b/c. It's not actually calling functions on a/b/c inside the switch statement; It is modifying the GUI based on whether you *can* call certain functions on a/b/c. Consider that the `thing` argument may be the "tell" in "tell-don't-ask" when *telling the GUI*.

Comment: `modifying the GUI based on whether you can call certain functions` makes me think of the Command Pattern in WPF.  The `ICommand` interface has two functions on it: `Execute()` and `CanExecute()`, which are wired via delegates to implementations in a Command object.  The Command object is bound to a `Command` property on a button, so that when the method delegate for `CanExecute()` returns false, the button is automagically disabled.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, But also modifying the GUI based on the state of a/b/c. A real example: a/b/c are actually classes that communciates with devices that have a temperature reading. All devices have a common temperature on `IThing.Temp` but only class `ThingA` has an extra temperature reading. `if (thing.Type == ThingType.A) labelTemp2.Text = ((ThingA)thing).Temp2;` There are many lines like this mixed in to event handlers where *most* of the GUI updates from `IDevice` and then hardware-specific GUI elements are handled by casting if possible.

Comment: We have a similar customization problem in a project I'm currently working on.  We solved it by using an [Entity-Attribute-Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model in the database and a UI that's generated from records in a handful of definition tables.  We never considered a class design; there was too much variation in each of the record constructs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Good to know about EAV if I'm ever running into this problem where there could be hundreds of types of `IThing`, like in a database. I don't think it's applicable, or appropriate, for this specific case because we have a finite number of devices we need to support (hence the enum to enumerate that in readable terms for our library users). The a/b/c are classes that "own" a TCP connection to the device, so they're already complicated enough and must be  implemented as C# classes.

Comment: @Romen I think you have misunderstood the tell don't ask principle because it is relevant and you are violating it. Again, if you are inspecting types, you should be delegating to those types instead. That is universally true in OOP. If you can t figure out how, post a concrete example and ask that question instead.

Comment: @AntP, I understand the "tell-don't-ask", I was considering asking a question about my specific problem where I couldn't think of a way to avoid it. Also, I find it interesting that C# has a language feature that makes it *easier* to do exactly what I used this anti-pattern for: [Pattern Matching](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements). Surely there *are* good reasons to "ask" an object about its type in C# if Microsoft felt it was necessary to implement a feature for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pattern is called “[type discriminator](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/)”.

It was very useful before OOP languages, for example to simulate polymorphic types with the help of [discriminated unions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminator). It is still heavily used and justified:

- in relational database when several different types of records are grouped in a same table (aka [single table inheritance](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) on the database side, because records have a very similar structure and differ mainly in their behavior);
- in heterogeneous and distributed developments when several languages are used, and you cannot count on cross-language polymorphism: objects are then serialized in one language and deserialized in another;
- in [event-driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming), when the event generation and the event processing is decoupled.

This pattern is however not to be recommended in OOP as a first choice if you're not in one of the situation above. It might lead to an **antipattern** when it encourages people to think in a case-based manner with lots of specific details instead of abstracting the problem and using a truly polymorphic design:

- The discriminator forces you to manually implement the polymorphism.
- Whenever you add a new type, you’ll have to update your enum and inspect/extend every module or function where the enum is used. So it’s not easily extensible.
- On the contrary, truly polymorphic design allows you to derive a new class, and everything you need to change is in that class. If the base class is used 1000 times across hundreds of modules, you won’t have to worry at all as long as you respect the interface and its contract.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still trying to figure out how we could have avoided this pattern in our specific use-case with C#.

Comment: @Romen it’s difficult to answer in general. Sometimes you can change form “do something with x” to “x, do something with yourself" in which case you’d have a method that each x would implement.  Sometimes it’s a mix doing some common things in handle but call a thing method to cope with the differences between a,b,c. Sometimes you’d look for a double dispatch, etc...

Comment: In my one particular use of this enum+interface, the "do something with x" is more like "build the GUI at run-time based on specific members of x's subtype". The `X` class implementations are in a separate library so they don't even know that there is a GUI at all. Adding a common interface method would require adding a dependency on the GUI library and passing the GUI into the interface method on X. The requirements of the library preclude having any assembly references to a specific GUI framework.

Comment: @Romen I’m not here to judge nor to convince you to change the way. I just point out the usual problems. And give you the name ;-)

Comment: Meh, this isn't an anti-pattern. If the enum wasn't there, people would do manual "is T" checks, which are even more fragile and un-serializable.

Comment: @Telastyn, Wouldn't using `is` for each possible type also be slower than comparing enums?

Comment: @Christophe, Would it be appropriate to ask a follow-up question on this site about how to avoid this anti-patttern in my specific case? Or is that more appropriate for Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Telastyn the antipattern is not so much the enum but the case/case/case everytime IThing is used. As said, there can be good reasons to use it. I've slightly reformulated to take into account your remark.

Comment: @Romen I think a follow-up question about design is perfectly in scope of this site.

Comment: @Christophe, A couple more questions: If I were to use the type-checking of the language such as `typeof()`, `dynamic_cast` and branch based on that, would this still be an anti-pattern? Is the fact that I am using an enum the main reason why this is goes against OOP principles?

Comment: @Romen I've rephrased my answer to clarify that it **might** lead to an antipattern. Because as told by Telastyn, there are perfectly valid cases to use such constructs. Now what I said for enum applies to [`typeof()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast): it's the same logic, except that the type value is managed automatically by the system.  The main problem is that it goes against the [Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open–closed_principle#cite_note-5) (see in particular R.C.Martin's article mentioned on wiki)

Comment: @Romen - ah yes, in most languages the enum check is _much_ faster.

Comment: @Telastyn enum is faster than typeof.  enum is also faster for a single check. But chained-if or even a case-jump table not necessarily compared to an indirect call: https://godbolt.org/z/BKwpxH

Comment: @Christophe - oh yes, absolutely. I am perhaps being too optimistic in thinking that developers actually use polymorphism rather than rolling their own for the common cases. But there are corner cases (modeling heterogeneous collections for example) where you're doing something more akin to pattern matching than an indirect call.